# How to set Currency Format in primefacs columnGroup?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to set currency format in `Primefaces` column group without getting string (with currency format) value form `JSF Backing Bean`.

If there is no way to set currency format in the page, I will take string value with currency format as below.

```
public String getCurrencyFormatString(Double value) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##,###.00");
    return formatter.format(value);
}


<p:dataTable id="paymentDataTable" var="payment" value="#{PaymentActionBean.paymentList}">
    <!--Other six columns-->

    <p:column headerText="Total">  
        <h:outputText value="#{payment.totalAmount}">
             <f:convertNumber pattern="#{ApplicationSetting.currencyFormat}"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>  
    <p:columnGroup type="footer">  
        <p:row>  
            <p:column colspan="7" footerText="Total:" style="text-align:right"/>  
            <p:column footerText="#{PaymentActionBean.grandTotalAmount}" style="text-align:right">
                <!--How Can I put number format (##,###.00) for grand total amount? -->
            </p:column>
        </p:row>  
    </p:columnGroup>                                
<p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Try reading this http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5880

Comment: But some custom code should be there.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use footerText. Instead:

```
<p:columnGroup type="footer">  
  <p:row>  
    <p:column colspan="7" footerText="Total:" style="text-align:right"/>  
    <p:column style="text-align:right">
      <f:facet name="footer">
          <h:outputText value="#{PaymentActionBean.grandTotalAmount}">
            <f:convertNumber pattern="##,###.00" />
        </h:outputText>
      </f:facet>
    </p:column>
  </p:row>  
</p:columnGroup>
```

Comment: This alternative should be in the Primefaces showcase!